# How to avoid initial focus on Focus-Trap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, focus

I'm using Focus-trap (https://www.npmjs.com/package/focus-trap) to improve the accessibility of my modal when using keyboard.

My code:

```
<FocusTrap focusTrapOptions={{onDeactivate: onClose}} >
  <div>
  ...
  </div>
<FocusTrap>
```

But when I use the mouse to open my modal, the first button already appears with focus (the ring that only appears when I use the keyboard).

[image]

To try to solve this I added `initialFocus: 'false'`:

```
<FocusTrap focusTrapOptions={{ initialFocus: 'false', onDeactivate: onClose}} >
  <div>
  ...
  </div>
<FocusTrap>
```

But I end up getting this error as soon as the modal opens.
[image]

How can I fix this? Is there any other way to solve it?

Avoid focus when I open the modal by mouse, only focus on the element when using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change from 'false' to false, an it's works